# file readline() returns nothing even though know there are lines of content

Tags: python

Trying to read some lines of a file (as done [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/)) and having problem where even though I can count the lines of the file, the `readline()` method for the file appears to return nothing.

Code snippet below (I have additional code showing how I am initially reading in these files to the system (via FTP download with `ftplib`) in case that is relevant to the problem (since I don't really know what could be causing this weirdness)). The `with open(localname)...` line near the bottom is where I start trying to read the lines.

```py
# connect to ftp location
ftp = ftplib.FTP(MY_IP)
ftp.login(CREDS["source"]["ftp_creds"]["username"], CREDS["source"]["ftp_creds"]["password"])
print(ftp.pwd())
print(ftp.dir())
ftp.cwd(CONF["reporting_configs"]["from"]["share_folder_path"])
print(ftp.pwd())
print(ftp.dir())

# download all files from ftp location
print(f"Retrieving files from {CONF['reporting_configs']['from']['share_folder_path']}...")
files = ftp.nlst()
files = [f for f in files if f not in ['.', '..']]
pp.pprint(files)
for f in files:
    # timestamp = int(time.time())
    # basename = os.path.split(f)[0]
    localname = os.path.join(CONF["stages_base_dir"], CONF["stages"]["imported"], f"{f}")
    fd = open(localname, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {f}", callback=fd.write)
    fd.close()
    SAMPLE_LINES = 5
    with open(localname) as newfile:
        print(f"Sampling {newfile.name}")
        for i, _ in enumerate(newfile):
            pass
        lines = i+1
        print(lines)
        for i in range(min(SAMPLE_LINES, lines)):
            l = newfile.readline()
            print(l)
```

The output looks like...

```
<after some other output>
.
.
.
Retrieving files from /test_source...
['TEST001.csv', 'TEST002.csv']
Sampling /path/to/stages/imported/TEST001.csv
5





Sampling /path/to/stages/imported/TEST002.csv
5
```

Notice that it is able to recognize that there are more than 0 lines in each file, but printing the `readline()` shows nothing, yet viewing the textfile on my system I can see that there is not nothing.

Anyone know what could be going on here? Anything more I can do to debug?

Comment: You can use `newfile.seek(0)` after you counted the lines to reset the position and to be able to read the file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on my machine if you add `newfile.seek(0)` to reset the pointer back to the start of the file, it works.

```
SAMPLE_LINES = 5
with open("test.txt") as newfile:
    print(f"Sampling {newfile.name}")
    for i, _ in enumerate(newfile):
        pass
    lines = i+1
    print(lines)
    newfile.seek(0)
    for i in range(min(SAMPLE_LINES, lines)):
        l = newfile.readline()
        print(l)
```

The only reason I can think that this could fix it is that when you run the for loop with the `enumerate(newfile)` that function itself is using the newfile.readline() function and is therefore moving the pointer.